# Xampp php log isn't working on windows 8.1

Tags: php, xampp, error-log

Xampp php log isn't working,it says path not found when I click on it.I tried to see the php_error_logs directory under php/logs. The logs directory to isn't there.

Comment: Maybe you have to configure the [`error_log`](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-log) and [`log_errors`](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.log-errors) settings in the php.ini?

Comment: If you could kindly tell me how to do that,it would be very helpful.Thanks